# How much the probability wave acts like a wave?

Tags: schroedinger-equation

A superposition of two probability wave creates standing wave. Well, that is convincing. Dose waves described by schrodinger's equation have other properties of wave? like reflection, refraction, polarization ect.

Answer (score 2):

Reflection, refraction and so on are properties of *physical* waves rather than of the underlying mathematical abstraction, but the short-short version is "yes", but the rules are necessarily different.

This follows because you make the same requirements of linearity and continuity at the boundary and there exists the possibility of different phase velocities on different sides of boundary.

Something analogous to polarization (which is a property of the class of *transverse vector* waves) appears in the form of the complex phase, but it is not exactly like the polarization of electromagnetic waves.

Comment: could you please simplify your answer further.

Comment: @KaziarafatAhmed The wave we are talking about is a probability wave, not  density of matter wave, and the wave nature does have mathematical similarities with the usual wave equations in classical mechanics but the manifestations will be different: the probabilities will change and there cannot be a simple way of intuiting or explaining this.

Comment: I want to know where the density of matter waves and probability waves gets difference.

Comment: Kazi, just set up the same kind of pre-conditions that you would use to get some behavior in, say, a electromagnetic wave and compute the result. If you want to see diffraction, set up a slit. Then you will have the results you want.